# Scaling Bounties

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

If a new user wanted to set a bounty on a question(*with less reputation to put up as bounty*), wouldn't it make sense for the more experienced users to be adequately compensated for their time and effort?

We've got spectacular members like Smarx and Rob Hitchens to name two helping out regardless, but i figured it would only aid in visibility.